# cypher- how to query for an unspecified year

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to query for a question that was posted on the april 1st but at any year this was my attempt

```
MATCH (q:Question)-[:TAGGED]->(:Tag {name:"perl"})
WHERE q.createAt = date({month:4, day:1})
RETURN q LIMIT 100
```

But I received the error

```
year must be specified
```

I was wondering if there was a way to specify "any" year. Or there was another way to formulate my query.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your `q.createAT` is a Neo4j date, you can do

```
WHERE q.createAt.month = 4 AND q.createAt.day = 1
```